# ColdFusion memory spike when reading csv file for DB import

Tags: csv, coldfusion

We have a ColdFusion 9 script that runs regularly reading a CSV file and inserting the records into an Oracle 11g database.  The CSV file has around 50 columns, 8 of which are used by CF (the CSV format cannot be modified). The general flow of the CFM is:

1. Read file into variable
2. CFLOOP using that variable as the list attribute with CHR(13) as a delimiter
3. Call an Oracle stored procedure inserting various values from the file using ListGetAt

The stored procedure does the following:

1. Inserts a record with 2 fields into table 1
2. Inserts a record with 8 fields (including table 1's primary key) into table 2
3. Returns nothing

This runs successfully in most cases, reading 400 KB files with hundreds of records in just a couple seconds. However, occasionally we get a large volume and end up with a 13k record 5MB file.  When we try to process a file this large I watch the JVM memory usage go from 90MB up to around 680MB over a 10-15 second period, after which the CF Server Monitor stops responding (as does CF) forcing us to restart the service. Logs report a JVM out-of-memory error:

> "Error","qtp4795249-38798","12/28/11","16:29:20",,"GC overhead limit exceeded"
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Our JVM heap size is currently 768MB. I haven't tried increasing it as even if that does resolve this issue it doesn't protect us in the future and the rest of the server's normal load doesn't require nearly that much. And I hesitate to play too much with JVM settings that require a restart to go into effect on a production box.

This is difficult to test as the import process runs fine with barely any noticeable memory load on my local dev machine and on our QA box, but both of those have a much slower connection to the database and take 10-15 minutes to complete.

I would appreciate any thoughts, especially about where the memory is going. I cannot figure out how 5MB of data gets turned into 700 MB of data.  We do have debugging information turned on, but the calling script's IP address is not in the debugging list and I used a cfsetting tag to turn debugging off for this page. Previously there was a step 1.5 that turned the CSV data into a ColdFusion query, but I eliminated that in an attempt to improve efficiency. Both ways result in an oom error.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  Due to month-end and year-end processing occuring with the customer, and their response to taking down the CF server for 30 seconds yesterday, we will be waiting a week or so before trying to implement or test any of these suggestions.  I will update this question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered direct import to database? For MySQL this is [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), for SQL Server it is [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). If you need some additional processing than possible approach would be loading data to the temporary table and then handling it with CFML, which can easily be done in batches for heavy processing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  We did consider this, but our DB guys are tied up pretty well at the moment and management wanted to try resolving this quickly in ColdFusion before attempting to write a new DB import from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than read the whole file into memory before you start processing it, loop through the file contents by reading it one line at a time.  Ben Nadel (of course) has a nice blog post discussing this technique:

[Reading In File Data One Line At A Time Using ColdFusion's CFLoop Tag
   Or Java's LineNumberReader](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2011-Reading-In-File-Data-One-Line-At-A-Time-Using-ColdFusion-s-CFLoop-Tag-Or-Java-s-LineNumberReader.htm)

Also see the [livedocs for cfloop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-71a7.html), specifically the file attribtue:

Comment: Those are good thoughts.  I will look into these and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: Ben's got some good stuff, but making someone leave this site to get their answer is not so great. Can you at least paraphrase what Ben says?

Comment: There's not much more to my suggestion than cfloop file="foo.txt".  What else should I include?

Answer (score 0):

We have a CF app which imports Real Estate MLS listings and ran into similar issues.  The core file we work with is pushing 100MB, and reading it in and looping over it at once created lots of problems.  We ended up doing a few things:

1. Split the file up into chunks.  The import process uses the split.exe utility from cygwin to split the file into 4,000 line chunks.  We then use CFDIRECTORY to get a list of the chunks and process them one at a time.
2. For each chunk, we read it in and then split the file contents into an array (using listToArray() with chr(13) as the delimiter).
3. We loop from 1 to arrayLen(chunkArray) rather than looping over the file contents directly.  This was done more for speed than anything else.  Within that loop we also break each row into an array.  We found that doing this and accessing the values as thisRow[i] (where i is the column number in the file) was much faster than repeatedly calling listGetAt().  The files we're importing have 90+ columns.
4. We increased the JVM memory allowance.  Our servers are pretty busy as it is, and this was adding some overhead.  We ended up pushing the JVM as high as it would go for a 32-bit server (about 2GB) so that memory was available when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at not looping over a query.  Some of the biggest amount of time spent executing queries is just making the DB connection.

Anytime I have to do multiple inserts like this from a file, I create each SQL insert statement and save them in a variable seperated by a semicolon.  I then execute all of those statements all at once every 100 statements.

I had to rewrite some procudures of another programmer by doing this and was able to cu the pocessing time by 90%. This was in version 6, so connections sharing may have improved this.

Comment: This was my first thought as well.  Unfortunately, the DB connection does not accept multiple statements in a single query and I don't believe this is something I can get changed.

Comment: Its not multiple queries in one, its just running them one after another, just as if you ran them in SQL PLUS all separated by a semi colon.  I'm not quite sure how the DB could limit this.

Comment: Are you asking about placing several insert statements within one cfquery block separated by semicolons?  That can and is limited by the driver used for the DB connection.  We're using the built in Oracle JDBC driver, which I'm not sure how to configure in that way.  I know that on my home server when using MySQL there was a checkbox in the driver configuration to allow/disallow this; gave me a headache for days before I figured it out.  :P

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am talking about.  And The default Oracle drivers with the default setup will support this.

Comment: When I try to do this I receive a sql syntax error.  The same statements work individually, or together in PL/SQL developer.  It could be something other than the driver causing this issue; I had just made an assumption based on my MySQL experience.  Any other suggestions where to look for this?

Comment: Are you preserving your single quotes?  you will need to do that.  preservesinglequotes(#myQueries#)

Comment: My test page for multi-statement cfqueries creates it's own test table with two number fields and one varchar field, the latter of which receives just 6 random A-Z characters. I still tried preserveSingleQuotes and tried removing the varchar field altogether, still without success. I still believe this to be a driver issue/setting.